# Lagrange Multiplierd for Economics

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, economics

An individual purchases quantities a, b, and, c of three different commodities whose prices
are p, q, and r, respectively. The consumer spends m dollars, where $m\gt2p$, and the utility function of consuming a, b, and c is given by: 
 $U(a,b,c)=a+ln(bc)$ 
Find the consumer’s demand for each good as a function of prices p,q,r, and, m. Show that when utility is maximized, the expenditure on each of the second and the third good is equal to p.
Find a, b, and c when utility is maximized.
 So I understand that my constraint is going to be something like
$ap+bq+cr=m$ 
Edit: A previous version of this post falsely wrote that $ap+bq+cr\gt2p$

Comment: Clarification: is $m$ given or not? And does spending money have inherent negative utility?

Comment: m is not given and I think it is assumed that there is no negative utility.

Comment: If there is no negative utility from spending money and $m$ is not fixed then you can gain unlimited positive utility by considering large $a,b,c$. So one or the other is necessary. What is not clear to me is which is being assumed here.

Comment: Good point. I missed that. I think the question might be trying to throw me off by giving that. The constraint cannot be ap+bq+cr>2p, but it must mean that the constraint is ap+bq+cr=m. Not greater than 2p, giving a fixed constraint. Then we can get a gradient of U which ould be (1,1/b,1/c) and a gradient of the constraint (lambdap, lambdaq, lambdar).

Comment: The point of $m>2p$ is just so that it's possible for the whole system to have a solution.

Comment: To be more precise, the constraint should be $ap + bq + cr  \leq m.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is best to set the constraint that $m>2p$ aside until the end, and then possibly eliminate solutions that violate that constraint.

$F(a,b,c,\lambda) = a + \ln b + \ln c -\lambda (ap+bq+cr - m)\\
\frac {\partial F}{\partial a} = 1 - \lambda p = 0\\
\frac {\partial F}{\partial b} = \frac {1}{b} - \lambda q = 0\\
\frac {\partial F}{\partial c} = \frac {1}{c} - \lambda r = 0\\
\frac {\partial F}{\partial \lambda} = ap+bq+cr = m$

$\lambda = \frac {1}{p}\\
b = \frac {p}{q}\\
c = \frac {p}{r}\\
ap + p + p = m$

We have no solution unless $m>2p$

$a = \frac {m}{p} - 2$